# how to fix this.backgroundMode.unlock() when not working

Tags: android, background, ionic4

i using ionic4

i import
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode
npm install @ionic-native/background-mode

in my project

i using code

```
   ....
   import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
   ....
   private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
   ....
   this.backgroundMode.enable();
   this.backgroundMode.isScreenOff( () => {
    alert('screen off');
    this.backgroundMode.unlock();
   });
```

when my phone is turn off screen not work
weackup and unlock

or testing by

```
   ....
   import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
   ....
   private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
   ....
   this.backgroundMode.enable();
   this.backgroundMode.isScreenOff( () => {
    alert('screen off');
    this.backgroundMode.wakeUp();
    this.backgroundMode.unlock();
   });
```

or

```
....
   import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
   ....
   private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
   ....
   this.backgroundMode.enable();
   this.backgroundMode.isScreenOff( function(bool) {
    if (bool) {
     alert('screen off');
     this.backgroundMode.wakeUp();
     this.backgroundMode.unlock();
    }else{
     alert('screen on');
    }
   });
```

or

```
....
   import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
   ....
   private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
   ....
   this.backgroundMode.enable();
   this.backgroundMode.isScreenOff( function(bool) {
     this.backgroundMode.wakeUp();
     this.backgroundMode.unlock();
   });
```

or

```
   ....
   import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
   ....
   private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
   ....
   this.backgroundMode.enable();
   this.backgroundMode.wakeUp();
   this.backgroundMode.unlock();
```

and BackgroundMode add provider in app.moudel.ts

but not working in all way
but working code

```
   this.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();
   this.backgroundMode.moveToBackground();
```

how to fix for using this.backgroundMode.wakeUp(); and this.backgroundMode.unlock(); for when turn off screen my device or my phone?

thanks